# Javascript: Equivalent Destructuring assignment for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am working with the groupBy function from the [dataframe-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dataframe-js) library.

I try to pass multiple arguments to the function (ie groupBy('col1', 'col2', 'col3')), however I don't know arguments in advance. I use the destructuring assignement: groupBy(...arrayOfcol). My problem is that this destructuring assignement is not [IE compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/Affecter_par_d%C3%A9composition#Compatibilit%C3%A9_des_navigateurs).

I don't have idea about using apply or call for this problem.

What can I use to replace the destructuring assignement for IE.

Thanks

Comment: you may have a look to [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), where you could hand over an array as arguments for the function call.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answers.